# Resizable HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am developing an web app on AngularJS, which has similar functionality to [Dev HTTP Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dev-http-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm) and right now I have to divide my web-ui into 2 parts and make the first one resizible with the element like this one:

[image]

so I could just move it up and down and the content inside the element gets resized.

Does anyone know how can I develop such element?
Please, point me to the solution, provide some links, articles. Every useful answer is highly appreciated and evaluated.

Thank you.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/resizable/

Comment: @NazarSobchuk have you done anything.....

Comment: If you dont want jQuery.UI resizable, then: add html element ater your textarea, add handlers to that element: mousedown: adds mousemove event handler which will rezise your textarea. mouseup removes that mousemove event handler.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this plugin before it's similar to what you want. http://layout.jquery-dev.net/documentation.cfm Here's the docs and here is a demo of it being used. http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/simple.html